# Проблема в реализации сигналов Django

Tags: python, django

Создаю профиль для пользователя, суть в том, что как только регистрируется новый пользователь, у него автоматически создается профиль, с помощью сигналов, сам профиль уже сделал, через админ панель он работает и возможность пользователю создать в ручную профиль есть.
**Когда я пытаюсь это автоматизировать, регистрирую нового пользователя, но к нему не создается профиль, ошибок никаких в терминале не возникает, не понимаю в чем может быть проблема.**

signals.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile, CustomUser

@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.ImageField(_('Фотография'), default='user_pics/default_pic.png',
                                upload_to='user_pics/%Y/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('профиль')
        verbose_name_plural = _('профили')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Аккаунт {self.user.login_user}'
```

Comment: @andreymal Не уверен, только начал знакомиться с сигналами

Comment: В `__init__.py` указали `default_app_config` https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Comment: @unknown Сработало, спасибо огромное, только не понятно, почему в том туториале, по которому я писал не делают так и все работает. И почему работает без `cmdbox.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Укажите в `__init__.py` файле `default_app_cnfig` приложения